# mod rewrite path in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite with the `.htaccess`-file in root directory the internal path `example.com/app/app-v1/` (including all subdirectories) to `example.com/app/`in the url, so that everything in the /app-v1/ folder is right behind the /app/ directory in the url.

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /app/app-v1/ /app/
```

but that's not working

Comment: Could you please share your htaccess file in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Well... there is hardly any code. I tried  `RewriteEngine On` 
`Redirect /app/app-v1/ /app/` but that's not working

Comment: Sure, thanks for showing it, please do add them on your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this code in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^app/((?!app-v1/).*)$ app/app-v1/$1 [NC,L]
```

`(?!app-v1/)` is a negative lookahead to avoid rewriting URI starting with `/app/app-v1/` to this rule.

Comment: Well done sir, you are GREAT in apache, truly. Could you please do let me know how did you get that we need to apply here negative lookahead in left side please, will be grateful to you, thank you.

Comment: OP wrote `including all subdirectories` and if don't use negative lookahead then it will affect internal path `/app/app-v1/` as well.